# GA Reporting API session and product correlation

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I ran into this issue a few months ago and nobody responded. It has come up again and I'm wondering if anyone knows why it doesn't work. Here's the original question:

[Correlating certain metrics with Sessions and Products in Google Analytics API v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701346/correlating-certain-metrics-with-sessions-and-products-in-google-analytics-api-v)

The issue is correlating products to session/page information. If you setup an api query with a session variable (e.g. ga:sessions) or a page variable (e.g. ga:pageviews) and try to correlate it to a product dimension (e.g. ga:productSku), it will always give an empty data set.

I'm wondering A) why this data can't be correlated, B) why both google's dimension/metric explorer as well as their query explorer allow these combinations, but never return data, and C) is there a way around it?

I've tried this on about 10 clients that all have lots of product data and the result is always the same.

Edit: Adding example report json for ease of replication:

```
{
    'reportRequests': [
    {
      'viewId': VIEW_ID,
      'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
      'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
      'dimensions': [{'name':'ga:productSku'}],
      'pageSize': 10000
    }]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After exhausting every possibility and attempting to contact google support about this, there is apparently no work-around. It appears that any session level information (e.g. sessions) cannot be correlated directly to any product information. Unfortunately, you are limited to the other product level variables or page level (e.g. page views).

In the case of this project, we had to re-define some of our metric standards for GA for things that google didn't support (even though adobe does).